# How to access variable inside app.use method in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, express, session, authentication, cookies

Here i am trying to access maxAge and expires inside `app.use()` and inside `app.use()` method i have `session()` and inside `session()` i am assigning maxAge and expires but it's not assiging the value to `cookies`.

**NOTE**: i am accessing maxAge and expires from a property file in real application

```
var maxAge = 3000;
var expires = 3000;

app.use(session({
    secret: 'Test API',
    name: "test",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave:false,
    rolling: true,  
    cookie: {
        maxAge: maxAge, //undifined,
        path: '/',
        expires: expires //undifined,    
        overwrite: false,   
        activeDuration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
        ephemeral: true
    }
}));
```